# Empty e-mail body using drupal_mail

Tags: emails

I'm using drupal_mail for sending eMails from a custom module. This is the code:

```
function changeme_node_update($node) {
...
$to = "receiver@example.com";
$from = "sender@example.com";
$subject = 'sampletext ' . $nodedate;
$body = "Dear " . $user_name . "! \r\nSome more text\r\n\r\n" . $nodetitle . "\r\nDate:" . $nodedate . "\r\nTime:" . $nodetime . " h";
$body .= "\r\n\r\nSome more text here";

//call mail function
$params = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
);
drupal_mail('changeme', 'information', $to, "de", $params, $from);
...
}



function changeme_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'information':
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'] = $params['body'];
    break;
    }
}
```

I'm receiving emails with the subject but the message is missing. Also, where to change the encoding?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using htmlmail et mail_system module ?

Comment: no, just drupal_mail, no need for html, just plain text.

Comment: You have used two $body's. Did you try using just one? Try including all your email contents into $body. <br> tag works, if you want to print the contents in the new line.

Comment: Yes, tried this as well. Still no luck with drupal_mail. I think i'm gonna use php mail instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
function changeme_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'information':
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
    break;
    }
}
```

`$message['body']` is supposed to be an array as defined [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/6114#comment-6114) so I changed `$message['body']` to `$message['body'][]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've tried but didn't make a difference. I'll try to dpm() my $body to see what is happening..

Comment: I've tried two things: 1) use $message['body'][] in the changeme_mail function: still empty message body in email. 2) i made $body itself an array and left changeme_mail function unchanged: still empty message body in email.

Comment: Are you sure you have no email template declared ? It might be an encoding problem ?

Comment: @marcmueller was this issue fixed? I am facing the same issue, I would like to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: No, but I haven't tried any further, I used the php mail function instead.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. The following worked for me. The code below should replace what you have set in the case statement
   `$message['body'][] = check_plain(t($params['body']));`

```
    function changeme_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
     switch ($key) {
       case 'information':
         $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
         $message['body'][] = check_plain(t($params['body']));
       break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an empty string for body is that Drupal is expecting an array, not a string. In fact, the function that formats the message, [`DefaultMailSystem::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.mail.inc/function/DefaultMailSystem%3A%3Aformat/7), contains the following code.

```
  // Join the body array into one string.
  $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
  // Convert any HTML to plain-text.
  $message['body'] = drupal_html_to_text($message['body']);
  // Wrap the mail body for sending.
  $message['body'] = drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
```

If you pass two strings to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), the function will return `NULL`, which (in the context of strings) is then converted to an empty string. (See one of the comments in the PHP documentation page.)

Comment: Thanks. I've made $body an array now. to make sure i used dpm() to show each of my $body variables. Still, there is no email body.. can drupal_mail be called from an other hook than xxx_form_submit? (i've only found expamples using this)